# MS Surface / Windows PC - Wipe Between Users

Tags: windows, security, powershell

As a company we have a few devices like MS Surfaces and some netbooks that are used for open access within social spaces.
The problem being sometimes these devices are abused and wallpapers changed etc.
As these are low cost devices they only have basic versions of Windows - so they are not on our domain server

What I have seen is some places have created a script that purges all data, resets the background etc - but retains the wireless settings.

I know I could script this myself in Powershell or Batch - but I wondered if there was existing freeware/opensource tools??

Comment: `Windows 8` and `Windows RT` has a built in feature called "Reset" this would wipe all personal documents off the device.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can live with redoing the wireless settings once the system is purged, then it's probably best to wipe the entire thing with the Windows 8 reset. Very simple process that only requires you to swipe and tap a bit. The following procedure is outlined on Microsoft's website. Here is the link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

Hope it works out for you!